# Turn on webcam from silverlight web site

Tags: silverlight

I need to write some site that will be able to turn webcam of the user machine and when the user will click on some button ( that will on the site page ) the webcam will capture the user face and send the face to some server ( i already wrote the server ).

Is it possible to do it in silverlight ? 
Can i access webcam thru silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what version of Silverlight and whether or not your application is running with extended rights. If it's SL4 and your app is Trusted, then yes.